# Application of the residue theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I want to prove that

$$\sum_{j=1}^n \frac{1}{\left[\text{cos} \left( \frac{j \pi}{2n+1} \right)\right]^4}=\frac{8n(n+1)(n^2+n+1)}{3}$$

for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ by using the residue theorem.

Which meromorphic function $f$ should I use to get the suitable residue?

Comment: $1/((z+1/z)^4z(z^{2(2n+1)}-1))$ should do (at least for getting the LHS)

Comment: in fact, $z/((z+1)^4(z^{2n+1}-1))$ should then work as well

Comment: $2n+2$ poles in fact (1 at $z=-1$, the rest at $2n+1$'th roots of 1). Those at $z\neq\pm 1$ come in pairs $w,\bar w$ and give the same residue (I hope), so you get twice the LHS (times a coefficient). The other two should then give the RHS - but I didn;t compute them (yet).

Comment: The sum is half the sum from $1$ to $2n$. I would consider user8268's second function but with the constant $16(2n+1)$ in the numerator. The tedious part is finding the residue at $z=-1$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are the details for my comment above.

Let us take 
$$f(z)=\frac{z}{(z+1)^4(z^{2n+1}-1)}$$
There is a pole of order $4$ at $z=-1$, and simple poles at the $2n+1$'th roots of unity. 
The sum of all residues is $0$. (There is no residue at $z=\infty$ as $f(z)\sim z^{-(4+2n)}$ for large $z$; alternatively, if you don't like residues at infinity, integrate $f$ over a large circle centered at $0$, and notice that the integral goes to $0$ as the radius goes to $\infty$.)

If $w^{2n+1}=1$, i.e. $z=w$ is a simple pole, then
$$Res_{z=w}f(z)=\frac{1}{2n+1}\frac{w^2}{(w+1)^4};$$
if $w=\exp(2\pi i j/(2n+1))$ ($j$ runs from $0$ to $2n$) this means
$$Res_{z=w}f(z)=\frac{1}{2n+1}\frac{1}{(2\cos\pi j/(2n+1))^4}.$$
Notice that the sum of these residues is $2\times 2^{-4}/(2n+1)$ times the LHS ($j$ runs from $1$ to $2n$) plus ($j=0$) $2^{-4}/(2n+1)$.

The last residue is at $z=-1$ and is $\frac{g^{(3)}}{3!}|_{z=-1}$ where $g(z)=\frac{z}{(z^{2n+1}-1)}=(z+1)^4f(z)$. It should be straightforward to compute, but I'm scared of doing so, and I asked Wolfram Alpha to do so (thank Random Variable). The result is
$$Res_{z=-1}f(z)=-(8n^3+12n^2+10n+3)/48.$$
The sum of all the residues of $f$ is $0$, and it does, indeed, give the result you want.

Comment: Nice answer. +1 I don't think there is a better choice of $f(z)$. And it would probably be a bit less tedious (but still tedious) to find the residue at $z=-1$ by determining the first few terms of the Laurent expansion at $z=-1$. Or you could avoid all tedium and just ask Wolfram Alpha for the expansion. :)

Comment: @RandomVariable thanks, I let Wolfram do the work :)